Can an increase in temperature for an endothermic reaction ever favour reactants?
I understand that an increase in energy will help an endothermic reaction but I know it will also augment the amount of collisions. That would favour the reactants if there are many product compounds compared to them because the products are more likely to hit and therefore react. So because of these two competing arguments can we always say with absolute certainty heat favours products for endothermic reactions and the alternative for exothermic?

increasing temperature will increase the speed of the reaction. If you want to know if the it favors the reaction check Gibbs energy

d(ln K)/dT = (Delta_r H)/(RT^2),  by the van't Hoff equation.

As a previous comment suggests, you should try to narrow down what you mean by "favour". There might be kinetically vs thermodynamically favored products: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Smith)/14%3A_Conjugation_Resonance_and_Dienes/14.11%3A_Kinetic_Versus_Thermodynamic_Products

See also kinetic vs thermodynamic control, eg https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/thermodynamic-vs-kinetic-products
